# Error in spring security core grails

Tags: spring, grails

I am using grails spring seurity core and very new to this. i am getting following error

```
Configuring Spring Security Core 1.2.7.3...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

**| Error 2014-01-10 09:40:36,688 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Assertion failed: 

assert SecUserSecRole.count() == 1
                      |       |
                      0       false

Message: Assertion failed: 

assert SecUserSecRole.count() == 1
                      |       |
                      0       false**

   Line | Method
```

The BootStrap class is as follows

```
class **BootStrap** {

    def springSecurityService
    def init = { servletContext ->

        //def userRole= SecRole.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER") ?: new SecRole(authority : "ROLE_USER").save()
        //def adminRole= SecRole.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") ?: new SecRole(authority : "ROLE_ADMIN").save()
        def adminRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
        def userRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

        //  def testUser = new SecUser(username: username, enabled: true, password: springSecurityService.encodePassword("password"))
        /// testUser.save(flush: true)

        //SecUserSecRole.create testUser, adminRole, true
        def testUser = new SecUser(username: 'admin', enabled: true, password: 'admin')
        testUser.save(flush: true)

        SecUserSecRole.create testUser, adminRole, true

        assert SecUser.count() == 1
        assert SecRole.count() == 2
        assert SecUserSecRole.count() == 1
    }
    def *destroy* = {
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code in BootStrap.groovy that's creating users and roles.

Comment: please show your `SecUserSecRole.create` code

Comment: static SecUserSecRole create(SecUser secUser, SecRole secRole, boolean flush = false) {
  new SecUserSecRole(secUser: secUser, secRole: secRole).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
 }

Comment: You should post that code in the question

Comment: An observation I have made (Grails 2.1.1) is that BootStrap runs (at least for me...) after all the tests. What I usually do is create my setup in a "public void setUp()"-method.